# Navigation Category page not indexed by Google

Tags: google-index, navigation

Navigation menu is in the form of categories on website `http://bankpo.in`, none of the category pages is being indexed by Google.

I searched with exact URL for a category, still related results are shown instead of category page. I have checked Google Webmaster Tools and there are no crawling error or any other error message, so I am really confused what might be the problem.

Website is not a new one and is continuously updated, so please can anyone tell me the reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't always index all pages in a site, in this case the category pages appear to duplicate content found elsewhere on the site.

Comment: is there any way to solve this ??? none of the categories are indexed, duplicate problem could be for 1 or 2 categories i think

Comment: I'm guessing this is wordpress, if the content is already indexed on other pages do you need the categories

Comment: yup it is wordpress, but some keywords in that niche that will strongly effect traffic on website are those specific categories. Google panda has already slided me fro 1 2 page to 9 10 page and now when i am trying to gain anchor through categories google isnt indexing them

Comment: @dhananjaigaur I see you have canonical implemented on the are you sure you have it implemented correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your website category pages own this following meta tag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
```

`noindex` indicates to Google to not to index your webpage.

To solve the problem, you can delete this meta tag from your category webpages. Your Wordpress SEO plugin (like *Wordpress SEO by Yoast*) can do it for you.